# Custom Pointer Cursor for Links Only

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am not a programmer, scripter, ect. but I have been fooling around with my clan's WOT website hosted on Enjin. I have recently found out about the Header and Footer code injection and have fooled around with it. I managed to make bottom bar links, music play automatically, a clickable logo, and (the one that took my ever to search for and find out how to make it work) a custom cursor for the whole page. But there is just one thing. I cant seem to find out how to make the pointer cursor custom for only when it is used and not for the whole page the whole time. I cant edit the div or a or p properties of the links except for the ones I have made myself through the code injection. So I am asking if anyone could figure out how to make this possible with HTML code. I have the file link if you need it, but all I need is a code to make this possible.
File URL: http://files.enjin.com/311035/wot_hand.png
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CSS and/or JavaScript for that. It can't be done with pure HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/bsjwnz2m/

```
body 
{
    cursor: url('http://files.enjin.com/311035/wot_hand.png'), default;
}
```

You could also use inline CSS

```
<body style="cursor: url('http://files.enjin.com/311035/wot_hand.png'), default;">
```